# Comparing power requirements using AC and DC to power radio equipment

Tags: power, ac, dc, current-measurement, power-measurement

I'm trying to understand the different power requirements for a particular piece of radio equipment that I have. It has the capability of being powered via a bespoke AC **or** DC power supply.

The AC power supply module takes in 230VAC and outputs 36VDC at a max of 5.4A.

The DC power supply module takes in 48VDC and outputs 36VDC at a max of of 5.4A.

The radio itself takes this 36VDC and according to the sticker on it, consumes a max 4A.

I started with the AC supply, and put a current clamp around the live conductor of the AC feed into the supply. The radio was connected to this supply and turned on. Interestingly, after say 30s or so I had a current of ~2.1A (the power supply according to the sticker on the back can take in a max of 2.5A). This seemed a little high, espeically if the radio says it can consume 36VDC at 5.4A max - or 200W. According to my current clamp, the power supply itself was consuming 230V * 2.1A or 483W. I wonder, if the radio itself could be interfering with the current clamps readings? The current clamp is an [RS Pro RS-330.](https://www.google.com/search?q=123-1936&rlz=1C1CHBF_en-GBGB954GB954&oq=123-1936&aqs=chrome..69i57.3872j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

[image: AC Block Diagram]

I then moved to the DC supply. I designed a DIY current datalogger using an Arduino, real-time clock, ACS712 current clamp and sd card logger. I tested my code and circuitry by hooking it up to a digital load - and comparing readings obtained versus the constant current set on the digital load. It's reasonably accurate - I would say with +- 100mA accuracy. I'm not looking for an exact current draw - just something to draw comparisons. I connected my current reading circuit between my 48VDC power supply, and the 48VDC power supply module for the radio. I obtained a max current of around 0.45A - so around 20W.

Edit: Just measured the AC current going into the AC/DC supply I have, and got a reading of around 1.4A. The efficiency is > 85% according to it's datasheet.

[image: DC Block Diagram]

[image: DC Current (A) against time (s)]

In both cases I have no traffic running through the radio equipment, just purely powering them.

There seems to be a rather large disparity between my results, too good to be true. Any suggestions or thoughts on why/what could be causing my values to be so different much appreciated.

Edit: As per @ jonathanjo suggestion going to obtain analogue ammeters to verify these results.

Comment: I hope this is not a condescending question but where exactly in the circuit did you connect the power clamp? Could it be that you were measuring the regulated voltage current? not the 230V but rather 36? Also, have you made sure to switch the power clamp to AC and DC measuring states(accordingly) when making these measurements? The difference does sound too large. Could you attach a schematic or picture?
Tom

Comment: Hi Tom, not condescending at all - typically its ususally a small mistake like this. But definitely I am measuring the live conductor from my AC plug. The output from the power supply module is a very unusual 6-pin DC connector. Furthermore yes, the current clamp is in DC measuring mode and not AC - with the range set to 2A initially then up to 20A when the current exceeded 2A.

Comment: AC also has "power factor"; it's possible the power supply has a low power factor, 0.5 or so.

Comment: @user253751 true, I would however expect a manufacturer like this (Ericsson) to have a better power factor than this.

Comment: It would make the most sense.

Comment: Is it possible that the AC reading is a peak reading over some period, perhaps even the startup current?  And actually the AC PSU is sometimes/often drawing a lot less?  I'm surprised you don't mention using a straightforward ammeter for comparison, that would be my first sense check.

Comment: @BrandonKellett You're measuring the live conductor from the AC plug with the meter in DC mode? Did you say that the wrong way around or are you actually trying to measure AC with a DC meter?

Comment: @jonathanjo I think yes its a possibility. I actually didn't have an ammeter or anything else available for testing - I think I will obtain a DC and AC rated ammeter and revert back to this thread once I have results from which.

Comment: @GodJihyo yes apologies, I wrote it the wrong way around. It is set to measure Ac and not DC

Comment: With a 200 W AC/DC PS, a low power factor has become unlikely: it probably is above 0.9 *at loads not too low*. 20 W is 10%, I'd expect better than 0.8.

Comment: I wired in this ammeter (https://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/ammeters/0244862), and for some reason getting zero reading. Even tried swapping ports. Is this something to do with the negative voltage being used here?